# Most efficient way to retrieve from table storage a range of partition keys

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

So for the partition key I'm using `YYYY-MM-DD` format string.

So the user can enter two dates they would like to get entities from so could be `4th December 2015 - 14th December 2015`.

I have the calculation to get all the individual partition keys:

```
start; // 4th December
end; // 14th December
var totalDays = (int)Math.Floor((end - start).TotalDays) + 1;

var days = Enumerable
               .Range(0, totalDays)
               .Select(x => start.AddDays(x).GetPartitionKey())
               .ToList();
```

Reading this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/#_retrieve-a-range-of-entities-in-a-partition) it shows that you can combine filters. However, I have `n` number of filters which will all need to be combined.

So I have a feeling this is not the best way.

How should I query this data?

Is it as simple as:

```
table.CreateQuery<MyEntity>().Where(x => days.Any(y => y == x.PartitionKey));
```

Ideally I just want to send to the server a list of partition keys and for it to return me all entities in those partitions.

**EDIT**

It may just be easier to do [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/#retrieve-entities-in-pages-asynchronously) then just filter those 1,000 records in memory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply write a range query. Something like the following:

```
        var start = "2015-12-04";
        var end = "2015-12-14";
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("MyTableName");
        var queryExpression = "PartitionKey ge '" + start + "' and PartitionKey le '" + end + "'";
        TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity> query = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Where(queryExpression).Take(250);
        TableContinuationToken token = null;
        List<DynamicTableEntity> allEntities = new List<DynamicTableEntity>();
        do
        {
            var queryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented<DynamicTableEntity>(query, token);
            var entities = queryResult.Results.ToList();
            token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
            allEntities.AddRange(entities);
            Console.WriteLine("Fetched " + allEntities.Count + " entities so far...");
        }
```

Comment: So if it is a string how does it do `ge` and `le` on it? is it because of the format of the string?

Comment: Also do I need the `Take(250)` if I'm happy with it taking 1000 at a time?

Comment: I used OData Query in my code (You could so the same in LINQ as well). And no you don't have to do 250 (Copy/paste from some previous code I wrote :)).

Comment: With the [Slazure](http://slazure.com/) Linq provider this could be written as: `var query = table.Where("PartitionKey >= '2015-12-04' and PartitionKey <= '2015-12-14'");`